# SQL best practice for case else

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql.
Just saw a place with a case statement with no else inside SUM and another place inside IFNULL.

Is this safe? Is this faster? what is the best practice?

```
sum(case when somevalue>100 then somevalue end) as answer
```

or

```
sum(case when somevalue>100 then somevalue else 0 end) as answer
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! These are different codes. Did you try them againist a table and compared the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These do different things.

The first returns `NULL` if there are no matches to the `where` condition.

The second returns `0`.  But it can return `NULL` if you have no `GROUP BY` and there are no rows being aggregated.

You should use the one that does what you want (usually the second is what is desired).  Further, any difference in performance would be microscopic -- perhaps not even consistently measurable -- compared to reading the data and other processing needed to process the query.  This is a "micro-optimization" and is rarely worth the effort of even thinking about.